# TornadoFx: Show progressindicator on button by hand

Tags: tornadofx

It's about TornadoFx' button.
If i use

```
button("push") {
    action {
        runAsyncWithProgress { 
            some()                                
        }
    }
}
```

I see progressindicator on the button.
How can I show/hide it programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

The `runAsyncWithProgress` function automatically adds and removes the progress indicator so it only shows when the task is running.

The function saves the current graphic property of the node and displays a progress indicator in it's place. When the task is completed, the old graphic is reinstated. You can however modify the graphic property at any time, as long as you do it on the UI thread. Inside of your long running function you can do `runLater { graphic = null }` to remove the progress indicator for example.